# How to fix position of values in column chart when filtered?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column chart, segmented by 6 categories (Total Revenue, Total Expenses etc...) and some year over year card metrics below each associated category for Revenue YTD, Expenses YTD, Total revenue month , Total expense month .When someone selects a slicer,  the columns move to the middle, which throws the alignment with the KPI's below out of whack.Is there a way to keep the columns in the same spot when sliced so the columns stay over the cards associated with each category?

I've tried a few things such as editing interactions - but looks like you can't do 'highlight' with the slicer and column chart, only 'filter.'

I want when someone select a month from slicer, it should display the matrix of that month below that month bar of column chart.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a version of your measures to return 0 when blank.
For example:

```
Metric = SUM('Fact'[Value])

Metric 0 = COALESCE([Metric], 0)
```

With the above, you have a choice to show `BLANK` or `0` depending on the need.

[image]

Comment: This is a brilliant way to use `COALESCE`. Thanks, Sam!